# How to check conditions for Liouville-Arnold theorem?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry, manifolds, classical-mechanics, hamiltonian-mechanics

Arnold gives in his book "Mathematical Methods of Classical Mechanics" on p.272 the following, well known theorem:

> Let $F_1, \dots, F_n$ be $n$ functions in involution on a symplectic $2n$-dimensional manifold \begin{align}
>         F_1,\dots, F_n\qquad \{F_i,F_j\}\equiv0\,,\qquad i,j = 1,2,\dots n\,.
>     \end{align}
>       Consider a level set of the functions $F_i$
>       \begin{align}
>     M_f = \{x:F_i(x) = f_i,\,i=1,\dots,n\}.
> \end{align}
>       If the $n$ functions $F_i$ are independent on $M_f$ (i.e. the n 1-forms $dF_i$ are linearly independent at each point of $M_f$). Then the canonical equations with the hamiltonian function $H$ can be integrated by quadratures.

Now, I have 3 first integrals plus the Hamiltonian in involution, let us call them $E,L,C,H$. In involution means here, that the Poisson Bracket is vanishing. How does one check the condition about the level set of functions? I am confused what the $f_i$ is supposed to mean. Are there examples how to do this?

Comment: Just from your quote I would assume that you choose $n$-real numbers $f_1,\dotsc,f_n$ and $M_f$ is just the intersection of the level sets $\{F_j = f_j\}$.

If the differentials $dF_j$ are all linearly independent along $M_f$ (which is generically true) then in particular $M_f$ will be a codimension-$n$ manifold that is tangent to the Hamiltonian flow of all the $F_j$.

Comment: What do you mean when you say that it is "generically true"?

Comment: The remark isn't important, I only meant that Sard's theorem of course holds.  I don't know what you want to prove, but maybe you could use it.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sard%27s_theorem

Comment: Your box does not define $H$.